# Convert a ASCII-encoded string to UTF8?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a string that is encoded with ASCII,
But I need to convert it to a string that is encoded with UTF8. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck. UTF8 is backwards compatible with ASCII<sub>[†](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8)</sub>, so all you need to do is this (assuming your input is a C-string):

```
NSString *asNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myAsciiString];
```

Answer (score 2):

ASCII strings are UTF-8 strings, because ASCII is a strict subset of UTF-8. No conversion is necessary.

```
NSString *myString = @"ascii string";
```

Comment: ASCII came first, so UTF-8 is a referred  *superset*, and not ASCII as a *subset*. You do also realize that this is the exact same as my answer, as well? -1 + flag.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII superset and subset are not defined in terms of chronological ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [decode dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
decode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```